# Spring Security issue - No matching pattern was found in subjectDN

Tags: spring, ssl, spring-security, openssl, tls1.2

I have a Spring Application I am trying to configure.. I had faced SSL related handshake issues... I think I have resolved those.. Now, it looks like the SSL Handshake is going through just fine. However, I am getting the below spring security framework error.. Trying to understand what this means and if I have to configure something else.. Can someone please help me understand this error?

```
* Connected to xxxx.example.com (35.xxx.xxx.190) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: xxx.cer
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=NC; L=; O=Example Inc; CN=*.example.com
*  start date: May 25 18:24:25 2016 GMT
*  expire date: May 25 18:54:24 2019 GMT
*  issuer: C=US; O=Entrust, Inc.; OU=See www.entrust.net/legal-terms; OU=(c) 2012 Entrust, Inc. - for authorized use only; CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1K
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /application HTTP/1.1
> Host: xxx.example.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 500 
< Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT, PATCH
< Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with, content-type, authorization, X-RateLimit-App
< Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-AUTH-REDIRECT-URL
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Fri, 07 Sep 2018 23:43:57 GMT
< Connection: close
< 
* Closing connection 0
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, Client hello (1):

{"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException","message":"No matching pattern was found in subjectDN: CN=*.example.com, O=, L=, ST=NC, C=US","status":500,"timestamp":1536363837143}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was an issue with the identity extraction.. I have given a expressiong for subject-principal-regex.. it was

```
EMAILADDRESS=(.*?)(?:,|$)
```

.. however the client cert didn't have a emailaddress attribute in the subject dn.. i had to change the subject-principal-regex config to

```
CN=(.*?)(?:,|$)
```